# I cannot clear my JTextArea, how can I clear the JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

It's a prototype for a virtual therapist, mainly for Java practice purposes. I've been trying to clear this `JTextArea` for 2 days now.

I've cleaned and rebuilt which got me through a few other hurdles, I'm at a loss for what to try. `setEnabled()` is coded out because I was just trying it on and off with different methods. Everything but the clear button works fine. I get a response in the text area after pressing enter with `JTextField` input. But it just won't clear.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{

   String inp = event.toString(); //this is input in a JTextField

   if(inp.contains("sad") || inp.contains("lonely"))
   {
       txtArea.setText(response1);

   }else if(inp.contains(""))
   {
       txtArea.setText(response2);
   }

   else if(event.getSource() == clear) //clear is a button
   {
     //clear.setEnabled(true); 
     txtArea.setText(""); //I've tried selectAll(), replaceSelection()
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified if the code path is actually getting executed?  Have you verified that the `JTextArea` you are trying to clear is actually the instance which is on the screen? Consider providing a [mcve] to remove the guess, the endless and needless commenting and ultimately to provide you with the best opportunity to get a reasonable answer to your question

Comment: the button is active now because I forgot to `addActionListener` to it in the constructor. However, it's printing the null string statement associated with `response2` which I'll figure out...

Comment: Well if a listener is missing: can't be seen in the posted code - you might consider to post more of your code. Otherwise see below for something that might get you a step further(also look at remarks)

Comment: @kai *"you might consider to post more of your code"* Don't recommend that a newbie post dribs & drabs of uncompilable code snippets when they have already been advised to post an MCVE. There is already evidence that the OP does not know which parts of the code are relevant, and an MCVE will make everything obvious.

Comment: I believe this guy that he is struggeling "for 2 days now". I hope he gets the hint that gives him just enough so he can go on  ... but maybe SO is not the right place and we need something similar for developers who are stuck to exchange and find answers.

Comment: *"I believe this guy that he is struggeling"* (shrugs) I see no reason **not** to believe that. But 30 minutes preparing an MCVE is a better approach to getting help than complaining about 2 lost days. *"maybe SO is not the right place"* It's an excellent place to sort such problems. ***If*** the person asking can do the minimum expected to present a good, answerable question. On that, there are **two** close reasons that list 'no MCVE' as part of the reason for closing. And a tip: Add @kai (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Yeah, I'm new guys haha... the corrections are welcome..if I don't receive them I'm not going to be able to function in the community here. Some people teach more harshly than others it's a fact of life..just cuz I can't write java YET doesn't mean I'm an idiot lol...just like someone who has trouble with english is not dumb even though we feel they are because it's easy for us.... (food for thought)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see in your code this might help with the clear problem. In your code the if branch for the clear can never be reached due to the else after an condition(contains an emty string) that is always true. I moved it to the front - so it is reachable.

I can't say for sure from your posted code, but the event.toString() looks also suspicious as well as the last(in the changed code below) condition, that is always true.

```
   //this looks odd/suspicious to me too!
   String inp = event.toString(); //???!!! this is input in a JTextField
   /* rather something like 
    *  if(event.getSource() instanceof JTextField){
    *      inp = ((JTextField)event.getSource()).getText();
    *  }
    */
   if(event.getSource() == clear) { //clear is a button
     //clear.setEnabled(true); 
     txtArea.setText(""); //I've tried selectAll(), replaceSelection()

   } else if(inp.contains("sad") || inp.contains("lonely")) { 
       txtArea.setText(response1);

   } else if(inp.contains("")) { //??? always true!! rather: inp.equals("") or inp.isEmpty() ...
       txtArea.setText(response2);
   }
```

Comment: thanks for the in depth feedback. MUCH appreciated because there is some code in there I NEVER would have considered without this. I'm not completely sure what you mean by suspicious, but the compiler seemed to have associated the variable `inp` to the user's input and the `txtArea` was able to understand what to do with that input. In regards to rearrangement, I tried that as well when it wasn't working, but gladly it was something extremely simple like forgetting to `addActionListener` I'm still getting familiar with "good and bad" practices, so I've been reading up on design patterns.